# I want to convert the pytorch model in python to c, any tools and methods to suggest？

Tags: model

For example, for resnet18, how can I convert it to c language? I tried tvm but the results were not satisfactory. I want the translated c code to be executable and to be used for inference and training

I use tvm but cant run the C code I generate.